# Not able to get particular string from hierarchy in Appium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, mobile, appium, ui-automation

I am working on mobile app automation. I am not able to get particular string from hierarchy [Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaTve.jpg) . I need to apply assertion for Ref ID present in hierarchy. But not able to find it yet.
I have tried to get it from getAttribute(), getText(), getPageSource() etc. Ref ID is dynamic part so it will change.